# Trying to get a Google maps to display in Django

Tags: django, google-maps

I wondered if anyone has managed to get Google maps working within a `Django project` and if so, could they tell me what I may be doing wrong.

In base.html, I have the following scripts at the end of the body in base.html :

```
<script src="{% static '/js/script.js' %}" ></script>
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script async defer src=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=”API_KEY”&callback=initMap"></script>
<script src="{% static '/js/maps.js' %}" ></script>
```

Script.js is working fine and map.js is executing but after map.js runs the div element doesn’t display.

In maps.js, I have:

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        //zoom: 3,
        zoom: 10,
        center: {
        lat: 46.619261, lng: -33.134766
        }
    });
    var labels = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var locations = [
        { lat: 40.785091, lng: -73.968285},
        { lat: 41.084045, lng: -73.874245},
        { lat: 40.754932, lng: -73.984016}
    ];
    var markers = locations.map(function(location, i){
        return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            label: labels[i % labels.length]
        });
    });
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer( map, markers, {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m' } );
}
```

I do not seem to have any Google API key issues. However I have a div in the index.html with the following element and the map is not being displayed:

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Map -->
    <div id="map" class="col-12"></div>
    <div class="col-12 mt-2 request-page">
        <h2>Map Will Go Above Here </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can get the map to display if I load static in index.html and place the scripts in index.html but ideally I think I am meant to do this in base.html.

I have not changed `settings.py`, `views.py` or `urls.py` to accommodate Google maps, is that where my error is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any entries in your browser console?

Comment: I have a message output to the console  showing me I am entering map.js and after the variable 'map' is set and when I log out the map object from within initMap I get  [object Object]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if there is a blank gap create a CSS file and add`#map {height:500px;width: 100%;}`
do not forget to link it to html.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably because the div element `#map` does not have a defined height. Try adding `style="height: 300px"` to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help, I just have a taller blank space. Thanks for the suggestion though.